# Angular: resolve html dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I'm resolving a service in $routeProvider I can inject the service like this and return whatever I want to resolve.

```
templateUrl: '/static/views/myView.html',
controller: 'myCtrl',
resolve: {
    myResolution: function(myService) {
        return myService.promise;
}
```

But I am using a library dependency that gets initialized by a directive in the matching templateUrl. To clarify, a directive in `myView.html` causes the dependency to get initialized.  And I'm injecting this into `myCtrl` for use there.  But in the controller this dependency is null, so its not getting resolved properly.

How do I force angular to resolve this type of dependency before injecting it into my controller?

Answer (score 1):

That library should expose a way for you to pass in resolves or a similar way to wait for data (for example, the UI-Bootstrap library allows you to pass in things to resolve before a modal dialog shows). If the library doesn't allow this, then your `myCtrl` needs to `$watch` for the data that the dependency initialises, and only act on it once its available.